# 'Invalid argument: output dimensions must be positive' when working with batch in TensorFlow API

Tags: c++, tensorflow

For object detection in video we are using batches with size greater than 1. But at the end of the video, when there is less frames than batch size left, we get this error:

```
2018-06-07 15:31:26.456907: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1290] CtxFailure at image_resizer_state.h:84: Invalid argument: output dimensions must be positive
```

For reading the video we are using Opencv 3.3.0, frames are stored in vector `batch`

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < batch_size; i++) {
  ret = cap.read(readImage);
  if (!ret) {
    break;
  }
  batch.push_back(readImage.clone());
}
```

That vector is transformed to tf Tensor as

```
tensorflow::Tensor inputImg(
    tensorflow::DT_UINT8,
    tensorflow::TensorShape(
        {static_cast<long long int>(batch.size()), height, width, depth}));
for (size_t i = 0; i < batch.size(); i++) {
  auto tmp = inputImg.Slice(i, i + 1);
  uint8_t *p = tmp.flat<uint8_t>().data();
  cv::Mat cameraImg(height, width, CV_8UC3, p);
  batch[i].convertTo(cameraImg, CV_8UC3);
}
```

You can notice Tensor is initialized with size of actual batch, so it contains defined number of images at the start, and fewer images at the end of the video.

After that we run "detector"

```
  std::vector<tensorflow::Tensor> output_tensors;
  tensorflow::Status status =
      session->Run({{"image_tensor:0", inputImg}}, {"detection_boxes:0", "detection_scores:0",
                    "detection_classes:0", "num_detections:0"}, {}, &output_tensors);
```

Which ends up with the error (`status.ok() == False` and mentioned message shows up).

So during the whole video we have no error, but when there are for example only 2 images left (so vector `batch` has size 2), but previous batch size was 5, we have the error and `output_tensors` has size 0. We tried to run our detector with randomly changing batch size for every iteration and there was no error when current batch had another size than previous one, it only occurs at the end of the video.

If we choose batch size such that

> video_size % batch_size == 0

the error doesn't occur as well.

We use TF built from [source](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow) (`master` branch).

Does anyone know the solution for this problem?